# What will be the remainder when 7^2020 is divided by 4?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Problem: "What will be the remainder when $7^{2020}$ is divided by $4$?"
I can't get a step to approach such type of question but all I know is the answer is $1$.

Comment: What is the remainder when dividing $7^2$ by $4$?

Comment: Have you seen similar questions? With possibly smaller exponents?

Comment: Start studying "modular arithmetic". And apply Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: @AlapanDas Fermat's little won't help, as $4$ isn't prime. You could use Euler's theorem, or the Carmichael function, but $4$ is so small that basic modular arithmetic is enough in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say Euler's theorem. I don't find why we don't say that Euler's theorem in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$7\equiv -1\pmod{4}$

So, $7^{2020}\equiv (-1)^{2020}\equiv 1\pmod{4}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $7$ is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ and powers of $3$ modulo $4$ are just $1$ and $3$

Answer (score 0):

Binomial expansion of $(8-1)^{2020}:$

All terms except the very last one have a factor $8$.

The last term is $(-1)^{2020}$, which is the remainder.

Recall: $(8-1)^{2020}=$

$\displaystyle{\sum}_{k=0}^{2020}$$\binom{2020}{k}8^{2020-k}(-1)^k$.